What is a solana?
ot error -32603 (Internal Error | Something went wrong within Phantom.)
My Code:
const createAndMintIx = createAndMint(umi, {
      mint,
      authority: umi.identity,
      name: metadata.name,
      symbol: metadata.symbol,
      uri: metadata.uri,
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
      decimals: Number(formData.decimals),
      amount: Number(formData.supply) * 10 ** Number(formData.decimals),
      tokenOwner: umi.identity.publicKey,
      isMutable: !immutable,
      tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    });

const instructions = [
        ...createAndMintIx.getInstructions().map(toWeb3JsInstruction)
      ];

      const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: toWeb3JsPublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions,
      }).compileToV0Message();

      const transactionV0 = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

      const res = await provider.signAndSendTransaction(transactionV0);

if (res) {
        return {
          success: true,
          mint: mint.publicKey,
          message: "Token Created",
        };
      } else {
        return {
          success: false,
          message: "Transaction failed",
        };
      }


can you skip preflight checks and share the tx hash.
